# Build frames for a text animation in Wand

Tags: python, wand

I'm trying to write an automated script in Wand on Python that builds the frames for a text animation by writing a caption of an image one letter at a time.

The problem is that when I write one letter using the caption command (documentation here http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.4/wand/image.html) it writes a giant letter, while when I write the whole text, it is fitted nicely in the image.

I thought of a possible solution: write the first letter colored and the rest transparent and cycle through that, however the caption command is not capable of doing multicolored text as far as I know.

If someone could suggest me another option I would be grateful. I could use draw.text, however that doesn't automatically calculate when to go on the next line as far as I know...

My code looks like this:

```
imgname = random.choice(os.listdir('/home/gionny/Downloads/HighResImg'))
text = 'Hello, world! This is a slightly longer sentence.'
fontname = random.choice(os.listdir('/home/gionny/Downloads/font'))
with Image(filename='HighResImg/'+imgname) as i:    
    font = Font(path = 'font/'+fontname, color = Color('#fff'))
    textWidth = i.width*2/3
    textHeight = i.height*2/3
    offsetLeft = (i.width - textWidth)/2
    offsetTop = (i.height - textHeight)/2
    with Image(filename='logo.gif') as l:
        l.resize(80,80)
        l.transparentize(0.7)
        with Drawing() as draw:
            draw.composite(operator='atop', left=i.width-90, top=i.height-90, width=l.width, height=l.height, image=l)
            for c in range(0, len(text)):
                caption = i.caption(text = text[c], left = offsetLeft, top = offsetTop, width=textWidth, height=textHeight, font = font, gravity = 'center')
                print(caption)
                cl = i.clone()
                cl.format = 'jpeg'
                cl.save(filename='Text/text'+str(c)+'.jpg')
                cl.destroy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If someone could suggest me another option I would be grateful. I could use draw.text, however that doesn't automatically calculate when to go on the next line as far as I know...

There's no quick way around it, you are responsible for calculating the x,y coordinates with each iteration. *Especially* when using mixed fonts pulled at random.

The method `wand.drawing.Drawing.get_font_metrics` has be provided for this sort of thing. Simply keep an accumulator & update with each iteration.

```py
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing


with Image(width=400, height=250, background=Color("skyblue")) as background:
    leftOffset = 35  # <= Starting position.
    topOffset = background.height/2;
    for letter in "Hello World":
        with Drawing() as ctx:
            ctx.font = "TimesNewRoman"
            ctx.font_size = 64.0
            metrics = ctx.get_font_metrics(background, letter)
            ctx.text(leftOffset, int(topOffset+metrics.text_height/4), letter)
            with Image(width=background.width,
                       height=background.height,
                       background=Color("transparent")) as frame:
                ctx.draw(frame)
                background.sequence.append(frame)
            leftOffset += int(metrics.text_width)  # <= Adjust for next iteration.
    background.save(filename="output.gif")
```

[image: output.gif]

Now for repeating the next-line process, just increase `topOffset` by the font metrics `text_height` if the `leftOffset` is greater than canvas width.

Comment: Thank you for your code, it was really useful to me! I also implemented the next-line process, however it needs some polishing up because it breaks words and also caption automatically calculated the size of the font to fill the image evenly... I guess I will have to figure this one out too ;)

Comment: Also I realized that the script crashes if I use my HD images, maybe because I only have 5GB of free disk space and the temp files eat up a lot of it...

Comment: I think you can figure out the rest. It's all basic geometry, and you can always post a new question if you get stuck. For HD images, your gonna need a lot of time & resources, and it might be worth exploring ImageMagick compiled with OpenCL/OpenMP & HDRI support. But honestly, I would ignore that problem until after your code-complete with the basic features listed above.